# how to put image in json as data

Tags: javascript, json, rest, image-uploading, oracle12c

i am working on a code for rest api in which  i am at page "imageTest" wth a image and button "onclick event" of the button will call function "foo()"

```
          @RequestMapping(value = "/imageUpload2/", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity profilePicTest(@RequestBody String data) {
    System.out.println("imageString length : " + data.length());
    System.out.println("imageUpload : " + data);

        return new ResponseEntity(null, HttpStatus.OK);
```

---

javascript part

```
    function foo() {
    alert('uploading image to imageupload2 url');           
    var profpic = document.getElementById("profpic");
    alert('uploading image1122334455')
    jQuery.ajax( {
        url: 'http://localhost:8090/EventApp/imageUpload2/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { img: profpic },
        success: function( response ) {
            // response
            }
    } ); alert('uploading done')
    }
```

can anyone help me in the part were i can upload image by javascript (with encoding like base64) which restcontroller can accept that image string further convert into byte[] array and inserted into oracle db blob column and vice versa to send it back

------problem part---- 
image not uploading in json as string
please anyone help me ...!

Answer (score 1):

The value of `data` should just be the file object from the input.

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="profpic" />
```

JS

```
var file = $("#profpic")[0].files[0];

jQuery.ajax( {
  url: 'http://localhost:8090/EventApp/imageUpload2/',
  type: 'POST',
  data: file,
  success: function( response ) {
    // response
  }
});
```

**Note**: This doesn't work in many older browsers. IE10+ is fine but anything older than that will require a different method.